# Snapshot timestamps not matching

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I want to run a snapshot test. When I run the tests, the only problems I have are the ones with timestamp. How do I fix it?

This is a component, which passes all tests, tested the same way my failing components.

Passing component

```
return (
  <div className={`accordion-section ${className}`}>
    <button tabIndex={0} className={'accordion-btn'} onClick={toggleAccordion}>
      <p className={'accordion-title'}>
        <Text isRtl={rtl}>{title}</Text>
      </p>
      <ArrowTemplate
        direction={isAccordionExpanded ? 'up' : 'down'}
        onClick={toggleAccordion}
        rtl={rtl}
        color={color}
      />
    </button>
    <AccordionContent
      tabIndex={0}
      className={'accordion-content'}
      height={height}
      isAccordionExpanded={isAccordionExpanded}
      ref={element}
      aria-expanded={isAccordionExpanded}
    >
      <div className={'accordion-text'}>
        <Text isRtl={rtl}>{content}</Text>
      </div>
    </AccordionContent>
  </div>
);
```

Passing test:

```
let wrapper;
beforeEach(() => {
  wrapper = mount(<StyledAccordion rtl={false} content='content' color='black' title='title'/>);
});
it('should match the snapshot', () => {
  expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

Failing component

```
<StyledButtonTemplate
  {...{ className, label }}
  classes={isTaskCompleted ? 'check-button-gray' : 'check-button-blue'}
  disabled={isTaskCompleted}
  onClick={handleClick}
/>
```

Failing test:

```
const checkAnswerMock = jest.fn();
const SolveButton = <StyledSolveButton
  handleClick={checkAnswerMock}
  isTaskCompleted={false}
  text={'Check'}
/>;

it('should match the snapshot', () => {
    expect(shallow(SolveButton)).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

Precise error:

```
expect(received).toMatchSnapshot()

Snapshot name: `<SolveButton/> match the snapshot 1`

- Snapshot
+ Received

@@ -1029287,11 +1029287,11 @@
  aria-disabled="false"
class="solve-button-blue"
  >
  <span />
  </button>,
  -             "timeStamp": 1568711150135,
  +             "timeStamp": 1568711193266,
  "type": "click",
},
],
],
"results": Array [

51 |
52 |   it('match the snapshot', () => {
> 53 |     expect(shallow(SolveButton)).toMatchSnapshot();
|                                  ^
  54 |   });
55 | });
56 |

at Object.toMatchSnapshot (src/components/SolveCheckButton/test/SolveButton.test.js:53:34)
```

[image]

Comment: what timestamp do you mean? in code snippets you've provided I don't see anything like timestamp. is it some string based on current date/time?

Comment: Can you please try removing `shallow` ? Is it required ?

Comment: If I use mount, the component is too large to be rendered in the test environment and it crashes, or takes forever to test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok adding this taken from here: https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/2234

```
Date.now = jest.fn();
```

at the beginnig of describe fixed it.

```
describe('<SolveButton/>', () => {
  Date.now = jest.fn();
```

Answer (score 0):

Something is calling Date. We can override it using:

```
const _Date = Date;
global.Date = jest.fn(() => DATE_TO_USE);
global.Date.UTC = _Date.UTC;
global.Date.parse = _Date.parse;
global.Date.now = _Date.now;
```

from [here](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/2234)

Comment: This didn't help. Putting it into it block caused an endless loop to start